# I am supposed to debug a SQL Server stored procedure but could not unerstand the use of ´@xx=count()`?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, count

```
Declare @Count tinyint
Declare @Count2 tinyint

SELECT @Count2 = Count(*) FROM  table where artno = @new 

If @Count2 != 0
BEGIN
    delete from table where artno = @new
END
```

I could not know what these lines of codes in the stored procedure in SQL Server are doing exactly.

I have looked into the definition of and use of `count()` after that as well not able to figure it out. Especially the `=` in the code confuses me a lot as well as `*`  in the `count(*)´.

I am beginner so would like to apologize if its quite elementary question, I got to understand though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT @Count2 = Count(*) FROM  table where artno = @new
```

gets the number fo records where `artno` is equal to the content in your `@new` varaible and stores that number in the `@Count2` variable.

```
If @Count2 != 0
BEGIN
    delete from table where artno = @new
END
```

deletes all records where `artno` is equal to the content in your `@new` varaible, if the `@count2` is not `0`

BTW the `@Count` variable is not used in that code and is obsolete.

Comment: thanks for the quick response as well as the explanation, but would like to know one more thing regarding stored procedures. Are the variables in stored procedures globally set or are local(functioning with in that procedure only)? I had to ask this since , ´@new´ is not initialized in this stored procedure.  The system has many stored procedures, and most of them using the same variable names. Yeah ´@Count´ is used no where in this procedure. This is was just a part of the stored procedure I presented here not understanding these only.

Comment: the variables are local. They get initialized every time the procedure is called.

Comment: Thanks again, but looking at the code it seems that `artno=@new` seems to initialize the `@new` variable, since if it does not, how would it delete the same `artno` from the `table`. As `@new` is initialized nowhere except this line. Some suggestions please, I am not sure about it but it looks like this looking at the whole code in stored procedure.

Comment: See [this example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de30f/5). You have to init the `@new` variable somewhere. It is not even defined in your code snippet. So if your code does not throw an error, the variable is defined somewhere

Comment: Yes, `@new` is defined but looking for its initialization. It is a `varchar(150)` and is defined but not set its value. `where artno = @new` this seems like condition as well as the initialization so I was confused. If it is a condition then it should be initialized somewhere in the code before it can be used as a condition, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be defined somewhere. Doesn't make sense if not.

Comment: I am unable to suspect working of this code, since it a working code and was written by some one else, now need to fix some problems, seems related to this procedure. I would better post the whole code instead, would be better I hope?